# ROBOCOPY /MIR (or /PURGE) follows and deletes target symlinks

Tags: windows, robocopy

Let's say we have a folder `SOURCEDIR` to be synchronized with `TARGETDIR`. The problem: if `TARGETDIR` contains directory symlinks, `ROBOCOPY /MIR` (or `/PURGE`) will follow the symlink, and delete every file and directory it points to.

The `/XJ` option does not work for `TARGETDIR`. Also there is no difference in using directory symlinks or junctions; both are followed and deleted. This seems to be a serious bug, especially if we said `/XJ`.  As soon as the target directory contains symlinks the copying operation can "escape" the directory boundaries, and more files and folders than intended go over board.

Any hints?

P.S.: For example, `ROBOCOPY` sync'd part of `TARGETDIR`, stumbled over a symlink, deletes parts of `TARGETDIR` again, then continued as if nothing happened. Finally you got a damaged `TARGETDIR` - probably without noticing. There is nothing you can do against it. But symlinks are a normal part of the file system. IMHO there should be an option to remove but not follow symlinks (like `XCOPY`'s `/B`).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see it as a bug. You're telling it to mirror it, or to eliminate (purge) the contents on the TARGETDIR that are not present on the SOURCEDIR. So, if the symlink does not exist on the SOURCEDIR, it'll delete it on the TARGETDIR. If you don't want that, don't use /MIR ou /PURGE. Or use another directory as the TARGETDIR. 
Also, with the information given so far, what you're expecting is unlogical.

Comment: Again, it does not delete the symlink, it deletes everything the symlink points to. At least should `/XJ` prevent this. Note that `DEL`, `RMDIR` and the Explorer have been made safe against symlinks, i.e. will not follow symlinks when deleting them.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. /XJ does what seems logical (to me). It ignores Junction Points on the SOURCEDIR, not on the TARGETDIR. Specially with the /MIR and /PURGE. Take a look at TeraCopy and see it does what you need.

Comment: Found ROBOCOPY /SL option which copies symlinks.

Comment: @AndreasSpindler Found a solution yet? I don't think will fix it: /SL follows the symbolic link and copies the target.

Comment: robocopy is full of bugs , do not use it  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e5a13ff-1dc0-4a34-9e99-37540c0fff60/serious-robocopy-bug-robocopy-vulnerable-to-symlink-attack?forum=w8itprogeneral https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/issues/1331